# Image Resize, Crop, Rotate Library for .Net Core MVC application

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a File upload option, After Uploading image I save it in the file system. Then I show an option to crop the image using cropper.js library with default x,y, width, height and rotate value.

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

In the UI user can change crop region, rotate, zoom the image then saves the image. Clicking on the save button I can pass x,y, width, height and rotate values to the controller function.

Now what I need is a suggestion of nuget package so that I can process the image in backend with the respected value (Rotate, Crop, Resize) and Save it again in the file system.

Anyone, please help me with any suggestion you got.

Thanks

Comment: I found this library is very helpful and worked for me Resize, crop, rotate
https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp

Answer (score 1):

There are many packages are available but this one easy to use as per my experience.

Use [Magick.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Magick.NET-Q16-x64/)

It's also open source refer [this](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/) for source code.

For more feature please refer the [document](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/docs/Readme.md) it's very easy to understand.

I have already use into my .net core project for images compress.

So it's also useful for you as well.

Comment: Thanks! man, Documentation says we can resize. But does not have information on cropping and rotating, may not support.  - @Kalpesh Boghara

Comment: @TokyoChakma Both are available By using Rotate() and Crop() method.
I m not sure why not include into document :(

Comment: I found this library is very helpful and worked for me Resize, crop, rotate
https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp

Comment: Can I use Magick.NET or ImageSharp in the frontend (using JavaScript)? As far as I can tell, they both use C#, which I assume limits its usage to backend or Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the javascript framework ([cropperJs](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/)) you can upload the edited images directly to server using the below method.

**First:**

Add the following script on your Photo Editor page

```
function uploadImage(file,filename) {
    var form_data = new FormData(); 
    if (file) {
        form_data.append("ImageFile", file, filename);
        var success_callback = function (response) {
         if(response.Status == 200){
           //images saved successfully
         }else{
           //probably image too large
           console.log(response.Message);
         }
        };
        var error_callback = function (x,e) { 
          //an error occurred
        };
        var your_app_path = 'Enter app path here http://...';
        var api_path = your_app_path + "/api/ImageSaver/SaveImage";
        triggerApi(api_path, form_data, success_callback, error_callback);
   } else { 
               //nothing to save
  }
}

function triggerApi(api_path, form_data, success_callback, error_callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: api_path,
        data: form_data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (response) {
            success_callback(response);
        },
        error: function (x, e) {
            error_callback(x, e);
        }
    });
}
```

**Secondly**

Create a controller to handle file upload (ImageSaverController.cs)

```
public class ImageSaverController : Controller {

    //  POST: api/ImageSaver/SaveImage
    [HttpPost()]
    [Route("api/ImageSaver/SaveImage")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(Response))]
    IHttpActionResult SaveImage() {
        Response Response = new Response();
        try {
            if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)) {
                object file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files("ImageFile");
                int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
                string fileName = file.FileName;
                string mimeType = file.ContentType;
                System.IO.Stream fileContent = file.InputStream;
                object max_size_in_byte = 1024000; // 1 megabyte
                if ((fileSize < max_size_in_byte)) {
                    object image_path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/content/uploads/images/");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(image_path)) {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(image_path);
                    }

                    file.SaveAs((image_path + fileName));
                    Response.Status = 200;
                    // Constants.ResponseStatusCode.SUCCESS
                    Response.Message = "Record updated successfully";
                }
                else {
                    Response.Status = 5550;
                    // Constants.ResponseStatusCode.ERROR_IMAGE_TOO_LARGE
                    Response.Message = "Image too large (max size: 1mb)";
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Response.Status = 403;
            // Constants.ResponseStatusCode.ERROR_CRITICAL
            Response.Message = ex.Message;
        }

        return Ok(Response);
    }

    public class Response {

        public int Status {
        }
    }
}
```

**Finally**

To use simply call the js function ('processImage') any time you need to upload an edited image to the server

```
//To upload image call the below function passing the blobUrl or 'data:image/jpeg;base64,......' of the user edited image
//Example usage:
$('#download').click(function(event){
//anchor tag : stop redirect
 event.preventDefault();
    var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
    var image_name = 'image_' + milliseconds + '.jpg';
//call function to save image
 processImage($('#download').attr('href'), image_name)
 .then(function(file){
    console.log(file);
    uploadImage(file, image_name);
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, It does not answer my question. I have no problem passing data into the server, however, problem I got with resize, rotate, crop from byte array.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can take a look [at the source](https://www.ttmind.com/techpost/How-to-crop-image-in-ASPNET-core-using-Jcrop)
you can get the **project** directly from [this link](https://github.com/A110SHT/image-crop-in-aspnet-core).

> If you run the **project** dont forget to navigate to Home/ImageCrop.

The Solution:

Create the input button in on the required view. After the image file is Selected and Cropped it appears in the image tag.

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="file" class="img" id="imgInp" name="files" accept="image/*">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="" class="img img-responsive img-rounded" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Download the JCrop plugin. [Click here](https://codeload.github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop/legacy.zip/v0.9.12).

Provide the link to Jcrop in View.

```
<link href="~/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/js/jcrop/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
```

Create the popup model in view So that user can Crop the image.

Home View Code looks like this.

```
@section css{
<link href="~/css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
<div class="container">
    <input type="file" class="img" id="imgInp" name="files" accept="image/*">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <img src="" class="img img-responsive img-rounded" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal" id="myprofilecrop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="cropmodel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div id="loadingDiv" class="hide">
            <div>
                <h7>Please wait...</h7>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" arial-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="cropmodel">Update Profile Picture</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="formimg">
                <div id="loader" class="text-center">Loading...</div>
                <div class="modal-body text-center">
                    <div id="views" class="m-t-15"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button id="cropbutton" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                    <button id="rotatebutton" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Rotate</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/jcrop/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/ImageCrop.js"></script>
}
```

**Source owner not using the “jquery.Jcrop.js” of Jcrop but he created his own custom js(ImageCrop.js) by taking some of the from JCrop as the reference in order to meet his requirement. Here is the full imagecrop.js code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     function b64toBlob (b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;
        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        var byteArrays = [];
        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }
        var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType }, { fileName: "ppp.JPG" });
        return blob;
    }
     function FileUploader (fileUpload) {
        $("#submit").attr('disabled', true);
        var fileformat;
        var imageonly = fileUpload.split(';');
        var contenttype = imageonly[0].split(':')[1];
        fileformat = contenttype.split('/')[1];
        var realdata = imageonly[1].split(',')[1];
        var blob = b64toBlob(realdata, contenttype);
        var filename = "pic." + fileformat;
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append("UploadLocation", "\\Images\\UserPhoto\\"); ///location
        data.append("FileInitials", "userprofile"); ///create files name with start
        data.append(filename, blob, filename);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: `${location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/home/UploadFilesWihtLocation`,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (path) {
                $("#myprofilecrop").modal('hide');
                path = path.toString();
                $(".img").attr('src', path);
                alert(path);
            }
        });
    }
    var crop_max_width = 400;
    var crop_max_height = 400;
    var jcrop_api;
    var canvas;
    var context;
    var image;
    var prefsize;
    function loadImage(input) {
        var isImage = input.value;
        isImage = isImage.split('.');
        isImage = isImage[isImage.length - 1];
        if (isImage === 'png' || isImage === 'jpg' || isImage === 'jpeg') {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                canvas = null;
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    image = new Image();
                    image.onload = validateImage;
                    image.src = e.target.result;
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                $("#loader").addClass("hide");
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("something wrong.");
        }
    }
    function validateImage() {
        if (canvas != null) {
            image = new Image();
            image.onload = restartJcrop;
            image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        } else restartJcrop();
    }
    function restartJcrop() {
        if (jcrop_api != null) {
            jcrop_api.destroy();
        }
        $("#views").empty();
        $("#views").append("<canvas id=\"canvas\">");
        canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        $("#canvas").Jcrop({
            onSelect: selectcanvas,
            onRelease: clearcanvas,
            boxWidth: crop_max_width,
            boxHeight: crop_max_height
        }, function () {
            jcrop_api = this;
        });
        clearcanvas();
    }
    function clearcanvas() {
        prefsize = {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            w: canvas.width,
            h: canvas.height
        };
        selectcanvas(null);
    }
    function selectcanvas(coords) {
        if (coords != null) {
            prefsize = {
                x: Math.round(coords.x),
                y: Math.round(coords.y),
                w: Math.round(coords.w),
                h: Math.round(coords.h)
            };
        }
        else {
            jcrop_api.focus();
            jcrop_api.animateTo([50, 50, 100, 100]);
            jcrop_api.setOptions({
                minSize: [150, 150],
                aspectRatio: 4 / 4
            });
            jcrop_api.focus();
            $('#canvas').Jcrop({
            }, function () {
                jcrop_api = this;
                jcrop_api.animateTo([50, 50, 100, 100]);
                // Setup and dipslay the interface for "enabled"
                $('#can_click,#can_move,#can_size').attr('checked', 'checked');
                $('#ar_lock,#size_lock,#bg_swap').attr('checked', false);
                $('.requiresjcrop').show();
            });
        }
    }
    function applyCrop() {
        canvas.width = prefsize.w;
        canvas.height = prefsize.h;
        context.drawImage(image, prefsize.x, prefsize.y, prefsize.w, prefsize.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        validateImage();
    }
    function applyScale(scale) {
        if (scale == 1) return;
        canvas.width = canvas.width * scale;
        canvas.height = canvas.height * scale;
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        validateImage();
    }
    function applyRotate() {
        canvas.width = image.height;
        canvas.height = image.width;
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.translate(image.height / 2, image.width / 2);
        context.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
        context.drawImage(image, -image.width / 2, -image.height / 2);
        validateImage();
    }
    function applyHflip() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.translate(image.width, 0);
        context.scale(-1, 1);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        validateImage();
    }
    function applyVflip() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        context.translate(0, image.height);
        context.scale(1, -1);
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        validateImage();
    }
    $(".img").change(function () {
        $("#myprofilecrop").modal('show');
        loadImage(this);
    });
    $("#cropbutton").click(function (e) {
        applyCrop();
        $("#submit").attr('disabled', false);
    });
    $("#scalebutton").click(function (e) {
        var scale = prompt("Scale Factor:", "1");
        applyScale(scale);
    });
    $("#rotatebutton").click(function (e) {
        applyRotate();
    });
    $("#hflipbutton").click(function (e) {
        applyHflip();
    });
    $("#vflipbutton").click(function (e) {
        applyVflip();
    });
    $("#formimg").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        FileUploader(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    });
});
```

Now Create Controller in Server which accepts the image coming from FormData.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace ImageCrop.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnv;
        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnv)
        {
            _hostingEnv = hostingEnv;
        }
        public IActionResult ImageCrop()
        {
            return View();
        }
        private bool IsValidExtension(IFormFile filename)
        {
            bool isValid = false;
            Char delimiter = '.';
            string fileExtension;
            string[] imgTypes = new string[] { "png", "jpg", "gif", "jpeg" };
            string[] documentsTypes = new string[] { "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "pdf", "ppt", "pptx" };
            string[] collTypes = new string[] { "zip", "rar", "tar" };
            string[] VideoTypes = new string[] { "mp4", "flv", "mkv", "3gp" };
            fileExtension = filename.FileName.Split(delimiter).Last();
            // fileExtension = substrings[substrings.Length - 1].ToString();
            int fileType = 0;
            if (imgTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
            {
                fileType = 1;
            }
            else if (documentsTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
            {
                fileType = 2;
            }
            else if (collTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
            {
                fileType = 3;
            }
            else if (VideoTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
            {
                fileType = 4;
            }
            switch (fileType)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (imgTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
                    {
                        isValid = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (documentsTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
                    {
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (collTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
                    {
                        isValid = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (VideoTypes.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
                    {
                        isValid = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    isValid = false;
                    break;
            }
            return isValid;
        }
        private string GetNewFileName(string filenamestart, IFormFile filename)
        {
            Char delimiter = '.';
            string fileExtension;
            string strFileName = string.Empty;
            strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString().
                Replace(" ", string.Empty).
                Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", "-");
            fileExtension = filename.FileName.Split(delimiter).Last();
            Random ran = new Random();
            strFileName = $"{ filenamestart}_{ran.Next(0, 100)}_{strFileName}.{fileExtension}";
            return strFileName;
        }
        public IActionResult UploadFilesWihtLocation()
        {
            string hoststr = _hostingEnv.WebRootPath;

            string[] strFileNames;
            ///string url = "";
            try
            {
                long size = 0;
                var files = Request.Form.Files;
                strFileNames = new string[files.Count];
                string fileLocation = Request.Form["UploadLocation"].ToString();
                //string[] path = fileLocation.Split("/");
                string fileInitals = Request.Form["FileInitials"].ToString();
                int i = 0;
                string[] path = fileLocation.Split("\\");
                if (!Directory.Exists(hoststr + "\\" + path[1]))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(hoststr + "\\" + path[1]);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(hoststr + "\\" + path[1] + "\\" + path[2]);
                }
                else if (!Directory.Exists(hoststr + fileLocation))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(hoststr + "\\" + path[1] + "\\" + path[2]);
                }
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (IsValidExtension(file))
                    {
                        var filename = GetNewFileName(fileInitals + i, file);
                        strFileNames[i] = fileLocation + filename;
                        string fullpath = hoststr + fileLocation + $@"\{filename}";
                        size += file.Length;
                        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fullpath))
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(fs);
                            fs.Flush();
                            fs.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strFileNames = new string[1];
                        strFileNames[0] = "Invalid File";
                    }
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                strFileNames = new string[1];
                strFileNames[0] = ex.Message;
            }
            return Json(strFileNames);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this library is very helpful and worked for me Resize, crop, rotate
https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp